# How to produce EPS instead of PS using latex.exe followed by dvips?

Tags: conversion, eps, ps

How to produce EPS instead of PS using latex.exe followed by dvips?

Comment: You are again constructing an overly long question. Moreover, I think that you use too many too large pictures (not only in this post). Please keep in mind that this is not a support center.

Comment: @Hendrik: I have modified my questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use instead the command

```
dvips -E  file.dvi -o temp.eps
epstool --copy --bbox temp.eps file.eps
```

Comment: I cannot understand why you need eps output at all. However, I installed TeXniccenter and run an example without any problem. Your screenshot shows that you have no correct bounding box values in the eps. This often happens when dvips cannot detect correct values from the code. Running epstool can help: `epstool --copy --bbox file.eps file2.eps` it creates correct bounding box values.

Comment: no, using the package auto-pst-pdf to create pdf images is  the better way. With the option `off` one can supress the creating of new pdfs when they are already present.

Comment: I am using pdfcrop nearly everyday and more than 5000 (!) images were created well ...

Comment: `auto-pst-pdf` cannot detect changes in a single `\pspicture`. It means if the PDFs already exist, any changes in `\pspicture` will be ignored.

Comment: The image is _always_ created new!

Comment: @Hebert: When I pass `off` option to `auto-pst-pdf` and PDF images are already created previously, are all PDF images re-created when I just modify one `\pspicture`? If all PDF images are re-created because of changes in one `\pspicture`, it will be a time consuming workflow. :-)

Comment: In other words, the current `auto-pst-pdf` does not compare the time stamps of `\pspicture` block and its corresponding PDF output so it cannot make partial updates just for any modified `\pspicture` blocks.