# Problem with rendering cropped eps files in pdf document

Tags: eps, dvi-mode

I have a bunch of EPS files which I'm cropping by changing their Bounding Box values. I put them in a .tex document and run Latex. Now, the resulting .dvi file shows the cropped figures correctly. However, if I now convert the .dvi to .pdf, the PDF file shows the uncropped figures, with all the figures covering the text as well. How can I deal with this? Also, I'm not allowed to use pdflatex, which otherwise gives the desired result.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE community. My humble opinion: Are they the .eps file with the same size? If no, do you should to crop times to times all the file .eps? :-( You can see if it useful this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171455/what-is-a-good-workflow-for-importing-and-cropping-eps-images

Comment: you should show an example of such an eps file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem in various situations. A solution seems to be to use `trim` and `clip` from `graphicx` instead of modifying the bounding box directly in the `.eps`.

To reproduce I made a simple eps file in Inkscape consisting of a five point star with a border. Some snippets from the produced file:

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%Creator: cairo 1.15.10 (http://cairographics.org)
%%CreationDate: Thu Jul 30 14:45:16 2020
%%Pages: 1
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 185 185
%%EndComments
%%BeginProlog
50 dict begin
/q { gsave } bind def
[...]
/cairo_flush_ascii85_file { cairo_ascii85_file status { cairo_ascii85_file flushfile } if } def
/cairo_image { image cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
/cairo_imagemask { imagemask cairo_flush_ascii85_file } def
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
%%EndSetup
%%Page: 1 1
%%BeginPageSetup
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 185 185
%%EndPageSetup
q 0 0 185 185 rectclip
1 0 0 -1 0 185 cm q
0 1 1 rg
[...]
102.664 181.711 m S Q
Q Q
showpage
%%Trailer
end
%%EOF
```

There are two places where the bounding box is set, once for the file and once for the page.

I tried changing each of the two bounding boxes to `30 30 150 150`, and compiling in two different ways: `latex-dvipdfm` and `latex-dvips-ps2pdf`.

I also tried using the original bounding box with the trim and clip options from `graphicx`: `\includegraphics[trim={30 30 35 35},clip]{originalfile}`.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] \textbf{Only file bounding box:}
\includegraphics{staronlyfilebb}
\lipsum[2] \textbf{Only page bounding box:}
\includegraphics{staronlypagebb}
\lipsum[3] \textbf{Both bounding boxes:}
\includegraphics{starbothbb}
\lipsum[4] \texttt{graphicx} \textbf{trim and clip:}
\includegraphics[trim={30 30 35 35},clip]{staroriginal}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Result in DVI file:

[image]

So: in the DVI file, only file BB doesn't crop, only page BB crops but is big, both BB crops and is small, `graphicx` does not crop.

Result after `dvipdfm`:

[image]

So: in the PDF file from `dvipdfm`, only file BB crops, is small, but overlaps the text, only page BB doesn't crop, both BB crops, is small, but overlaps the text, `graphicx` crops, is small, does not overlap.

Result after `dvips-ps2pdf`:

[image]

So: in the PDF file from `dvips-ps2pdf`, only file BB does not crop and overlaps the text, only page BB doesn't crop but does not overlap, both BB doesn't crop and overlaps, `graphicx` crops, is small, does not overlap.

As a table, bold for correct results:

| bounding box | compiler | size | crop | overlap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| only file | latex | small | no | no |
|  | dvipdfm | small | yes | yes |
|  | dvips | big | no | yes |
| only page | latex | big | yes | no |
|  | dvipdfm | big | no | no |
|  | dvips | big | no | no |
| both | latex | **small** | **yes** | **no** |
|  | dvipdfm | small | yes | yes |
|  | dvips | big | no | yes |
| trim and clip | latex | small | no | no |
|  | dvipdfm | **small** | **yes** | **no** |
|  | dvips | **small** | **yes** | **no** |