# How to crop .eps and use in Latex

Tags: pdf, includegraphics, eps, crop

How do I crop an .eps file for use in LaTeX when using macOS?

I tried the instructions here: [What is a good workflow for importing and cropping EPS images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171455/what-is-a-good-workflow-for-importing-and-cropping-eps-images) and it didn't work.

Specifically,

- I began with an .eps file generated by TGIF (call it `image_v1.eps`)
- I opened `image_v1.eps` in Preview.app
- I Used Preview to crop the image and saved the cropped image in `image_v2.pdf`.  Now, because cropping an image in Preview.app just hides the cropped material as opposed to removing it,
- I ran `pdfcrop --clip image_v2.pdf image_v3.pdf`
- Then I ran `pdf2ps image_v3.pdf image_v3.eps`
- Finally, I included it in my LaTeX document using

  `\fbox{\includegraphics[width=3in]{image_v3.eps}}`

The result is that the entire original .eps file is displayed, but the `fbox` only appears around cropped portion of the image.

- Adding a `trim` parameter to `includegraphics` changes the `fbox`, but the "extra" portion of the image is still displayed.
- Similarly, editing the .eps file and changing the bounding box information changes the size of the `fbox` but the "extra" portion of the image is still displayed.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Should I be using a different tool at any point above?

To be clear:  Adding `clip=true` to the `includegraphics` command does hide the unwanted portion of the image.  However, I want to edit the .eps file so it only contains the image I want to display.  I'd rather not resort to "tricking" LaTeX into displaying only part of the image.

Comment: Search for the bounding box `bb` and `clip` options to include the eps file.

Comment: Yes, you can clip the inserted image.

Comment: It is quite difficult to remove parts from a vector graphic. That's why all cropping and clipping only hides things.

Comment: is there a particular reason to use latex and include eps rather than use pdflatex and include pdf?

Comment: I suppose I could.  But, every other document uses latex and eps.  All else being equal it seems easier to keep this document consistent with the others.  (I teach, so I have a lot of assignments and tests prepared in latex.)

Comment: well it doesn't make so much difference but eps is very 1980s and not so much used these days. I'm not sure pdf2ps makes eps you could try `pdftops -eps image_v3.pdf image_v3.eps` if you have `ppdftops` installed (note `to` not `2`) or simply edit the `%%BoundingBox in the file`

Comment: I tried editing the BoundingBox in the EPS file, and it had the same effect:  The \fbox changed accordingly, but the "cropped" image outside the bounding box was still displayed.

Comment: Where would I get pdftops?  It's not installed on my mac, and my Google skills are failing me.  I have seen several articles pointing to using pdf2ps with the `-eps` flag; but my installed version of that tool doesn't recognize that switch.