# EPS file is too large to be in one page

Tags: graphics, pdftex, eps

The eps file is very large. If it is forced to be in one page, then labels in the figure are too small to read, especially when print.

Is it possible to let this eps file cross pages during latex compilation?  Any other solutions?

In latext, the source eps file is in the link [1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rk9big3rngc7qfx/DYNGuardWithTestHandle820_dot_generated.eps?dl=0), and it is included as

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=.29, angle=90]{graphjit/DYNGuardWithTestHandle820_dot_source}  
  \caption{\textcolor{red}{Set \textit{equivalent} to be $G_{root}$}}
  \label{fig:dot_source}
\end{figure}
```

And the output is in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T15gn.png).

[image: Result in pdf after latext compilation]

Comment: Probably it is a problem related a incorrect bounding box of your eps file. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22063/how-to-fix-eps-with-incorrect-bounding-box

Comment: You could crop it into two separate parts: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image

Comment: if you only make pdf then you can simply make that page bigger, but that doesn't work well if the document is intended for paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cut down the image in pieces using the `viewport` and `clip` options of `\includegraphics`. See the docs of package `graphicx` for the details.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[viewport=0 0 3in 5in,clip]{example-image-a}
\newpage
\includegraphics[viewport=3in 0 6in 5in,clip]{example-image-a}
\end{document}
```

[image]