# How to convert a dvi file to an encapsulated postscript file?

Tags: eps, dvi, postscript

I heard that we can use `dvips –E` to convert dvi to encapsulated postscript. But I do not know what is `dvips -E`. I can not find a command like "dvips -E" in my Texmaker.

Clearly, I am a rookie. Can somebody explain it to me?

Comment: It's a bash command, that you input in your terminal (just like you can enter `latex <filename>`). When using TeXmaker (that is an *IDE*), it's the programm itself that launchs bash-commans (like `latex`, `biber`, etc.) so you are usually not aware of this mechanism. If you never heard of command line... welcome into a new world!

Comment: @ebo, Thank you very much for your comment. It seems that you are saying that I can do this conversion in the terminal? I will try that.

Comment: Yes, `dvips –E` is for converting the file from your terminal. see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7901/64454

Comment: The command line for dvips in TeXmaker, as seen in `Options -> Configure TeXmaker` is `dvips -Pdownload35 -o %.ps %.dvi`.  You can change it  temporarily to `dvips -Pdownload35 -E -o %.eps %.dvi`, or create a macro which executes this command.